# Creating Webservice with webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, web-services, razor, web, webmatrix

this time i learn how to create webservice with webmatrix.
I try learn from this link :
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/creating-a-webservice-with-webmatrix-and-consuming-it-with-a-windows-7-phone-application
but i stuck because author didn't sample source code.
This is my getproduct.cshtml code :

```
@{
    public class Product {
        public string Name {get; set; }
        public int Price {get; set; }
    }

    public static Product GetProducts(string price) {
        var db = Database.Open("WebService");
        var selectQueryString = "SELECT Name, Score FROM Users WHERE Score >= " + @price;
        var data = db.Query(selectQueryString);
        Product product = new Product(); 
        foreach (var row in data) {
            product.Name = @row.Name;
            product.Price = @row.Score;
        } 
        return product; 
    }
}
```

This is my jsonRequest.cshtml code :

```
@{
    var price = Request.QueryString["price"];
        if (price == null || price == string.Empty) {
            <p>Please enter a Price value</p>
        }  else {
            var product = getproduct.GetProducts(price);
            Json.Write(product, Response.Output);
        }
}
```

okay and last i run `http://localhost:55278/jsonRequest.cshtml`, but there are two error for me, that are :
1. that address there is no QueryString, and code just past if to else.
2. error in getproductGetProduct(price);

> CS0117: 'ASP.getproduct' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetProduct'

please help me, how to solve my problem, so that i can finish that tutorial from that link.
thank you

```
---UPDATE----
this is my folder 
Test Webservice
|-jsonRequest.cshtml
|-App_Code
   |-getproduct.cshtml
```

Comment: I updated my answer to match your edit, but it looks like your primary issue is to carefully compare your object and method names both for spelling and case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue I can see is just one of case-sensitivity:

```
var product = getproduct.GetProduct(price);
```

Should be:

```
var product = getProduct.GetProduct(price);
```

The object name is case-sensitive and must be exactly the same as the name of the `.cshtml` file in the `App_Code` folder.

---

You seem to have edited your question to show that the case was correct originally, so the next problem I see is in the name of your method being plural. Your method signature is:

```
public static Product GetProducts(string price)
```

So you need to change:

```
var product = getproduct.GetProduct(price);
```

To:

```
var product = getproduct.GetProducts(price);
```

---

In your `getproduct.cshtml` you need to change the opening of the block from `@{` to `@functions {`.

I know you're only following a tutorial too so this is just an aside, but that code looks absolutely ripe for an SQL injection hack to me.

Comment: thanks dude, sorry i edit the question but i didn't inform you, i try it first :D

Comment: Sory @Polynomial your solution still didnt work :(, btw i update my question with folder tree. Is the arrangement of folder tree correct?

Comment: @yozawiratama What is the current error message you're getting? The one in your question now doesn't match your code.

Comment: this is my current error message : CS0117: 'ASP.getproduct' does not contain a definition for 'GetProducts'

Comment: @yozawiratama See the new edit, hopefully that's it!

Comment: "...but that code looks absolutely ripe for an SQL injection hack to me." please teach me how to handle that problem, :( i want to learn make webservice, so that i can consume it from other client tool :(

Comment: @yozawiratama Make `GetProducts()` accept a `decimal` parameter instead of `string` and in your `jsonRequest.cshtml` you can do `Request.QueryString["price"].AsDecimal();`. Read up on SQL injection hacks to see why this is important.